# what's the use of "declare -i "

Tags: shell

i meet a code like this, it seem use declare -i to declare variable . i want know why we use it here , and not  use
     before_datetime=`date --date="$BEFORE" +%s`
directly .

```
:::shell
get_timestamp() {
    BEFORE=$1   
    AFTER=$2
    TOTAL_HR=$3

    BEFORE=$(echo $BEFORE)
    AFTER=$(echo $AFTER)

    declare -i before_datetime=`date --date="$BEFORE" +%s`
    declare -i after_datetime=`date --date="$AFTER" +%s`
    declare -i date_total_s=$(($after_datetime-$before_datetime))
    date_hr=$(echo "scale=5; $date_total_s/60/60" | bc -l)  
    TOTAL_HR=$(echo "scale=5; $TOTAL_HR+$date_hr" | bc -l)
        echo $TOTAL_HR
 }
```

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will get the same result but the `-i` flag means that the variable is declared as an integer (rather than a string or other type).

By declaring it as an integer it means that no type casting has to be done (e.g. converting a string to an int) later on and just makes it clear as you read the code that those variables are definitely integers.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out `declare -i` indicates an integer, but there is another reason to use `declare` in a function - it makes a variable local to the function (the -i is not required for that, it adds the integer property as well).  This can also be done using the `local` command.

For example, in your function the variables BEFORE, AFTER, and TOTAL_HR are all global, which might be an issue if you are calling functions from functions.

Answer (score 0):

**The integer attribute (declare -i)**

Having the *integer attribute* on a variable changes the way the `=` and `+=` operators works.

**The `=` operator**

From `man bash`:

> If the variable has its integer attribute set, then value is evaluated
>   as an arithmetic expression even if the $((...)) expansion is not
>   used.

Example:

```
i=1+2
declare -i j=1+2
echo "With integer attribute unset: $i" # Returns "1+2"
echo "With integer attribute set: $j"   # Returns "3"
```

**The `+=` operator**

From `man bash`:

> [...] the += operator can be used to append to or add to the
>   variable's previous value.  When +=  is  applied to  a  variable  for 
>   which  the integer attribute has been set, value is evaluated as an
>   arithmetic expression and added to the variable's current value, which
>   is also evaluated. [...] When applied to a string-valued variable,
>   value is expanded and appended to the variable's value

Example:

```
i=1
declare -i j=1
i+=2
j+=2
echo "With integer attribute unset: $i" # Returns "12"
echo "With integer attribute set: $j"   # Returns "3"
```

Answer (score -1):

Just my 2 cents how you could find the answer by yourself.

You run `man bash` and search section describing `declare`.

However there's "faster" way. For each bash *builtin* command you can run help in the following way:

```
help declare
```

The output is:

```
.......
Options which set attributes:
  -a        to make NAMEs indexed arrays (if supported)
  -A        to make NAMEs associative arrays (if supported)
  -i        to make NAMEs have the `integer' attribute
  -l        to convert NAMEs to lower case on assignment
  .....
```